# How to avoid iteration custom keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How would I write something in tensorFlow that would have the same result as

```py
cnt = [tf.reduce_max(tf.divide(outs[i], self.b[1:, i])) for i in range(self.filters)]
```

This must be able to run on Graph execution, and I just need to increase the effeciency of this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `tf.reduce_max(tf.divide(outs, self.b[1:]), axis=1)` works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
@tf.function
def func(**kwargs):
  cnt = [tf.reduce_max(tf.divide(outs[i], self.b[1:, i])) for i in range(self.filters)]
  return cnt
```

@tf.function uses the graph execution,